# multiple select with 3 values for each option to SQL send

Tags: javascript, php, sql, vue.js

I have a very tricky question and I should work long hours on this problem and look for a solution.

Suppose I have a multiple select and there are more options, each option has 3 values:

- one value for the language name
- one is a link to the language icon (img)
- one is the language level.

in database "SQL" i have 4 columns

- 1. id
- 2. sprachename
- 3.spracheicon
- 4.sprachlevel

If I have a language then select 3 values should be in different columns in MYSQL (language name value should be in language name column and the link value should also be in its own column, etc.)

So how could I do that?

```html
<select
  class="multi-select" 
  name=""
  id=""
  multiple
  v-model="sprachen"
>
  <option 
    value="Arabic"
    value="Muttersprache" 
    value="https://bilder.pcwelt.de/4204696_620x310_r.jpg" 
  >
    Arabisch
  </option>
  <option 
    value="Englisch" 
    value="B1" 
    value="https://bilder.pcwelt.de/4204696_620x310_r.jpg" 
  >
    Englisch
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "each option has 3 values". Can you show us an example of the HTML of this multiple select, please?

Comment: hey, i added example

Comment: You can only have one value field, make it an array, , seperated.

Comment: Why do you need those extra values? Is "Englisch" not enough to send back to the database? or have you got other "Englisch" options in the select where the other values are not the same? Anyway, I suggest sending back a single code/ID which represents that combination of values. You can store a lookup table in your database which matches the code to the combination.

Comment: It is a school task, I create a simple profile and the user can enter the languages he speaks

Comment: Ok. That doesn't actually answer my question though. I am guessing maybe English appears twice? Maybe once as mother tongue and once as second language? Am I correct?

Comment: It's just an example, so for me, arabic is mother tongue and english is level B1

Comment: Sure. But maybe the user can, from the same select, choose English as mother tongue instead? If you want them to be able choose that, you need another `<option` for it. This is what I'm trying to understand, whether there are different combinations of the various values? If not, then there's simply no point in having them. What I'm asking for is a more complete set of examples which demonstrates why you needed to have these multiple values

Comment: Yes, you are right, I wanted to make these options, but I don't know how to do it, and I didn't want to disturb you :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple `value` attributes in one `option`. Only one value can be submitted.

It seems you're looking to be able to support different variations of the main options, e.g.

```
Arabic - mother tongue
Arabic - Level B1
English - mother tongue
English - Level B1
```

or something similar, and were hoping that you could control this by setting multiple values on each option.

A standard approach to this kind of thing is as follows:

1. Define a table in your database which lists all the possible options and their attributes, and acts as a reference from which you can populate your `select`. Crucially it also has a unique ID for each row, to identify that option specifically.

e.g. You would have a `LanguageOptions` table. A few rows of the contents would look like this:

| ID | Description | Lang | Level | Image |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Arabic - mother tongue | AR | M | https://bilder.pcwelt.de/4204696_620x310_r.jpg |
| 2 | Arabic - Level B1 | AR | B1 | https://example.com/1.jpg |
| 3 | English - mother tongue | EN | M | https://example.com/2.jpg |
| 4 | English - Level B1 | EN | B1 | https://example.com/3.jpg |

2. This means in your `<select>` you can use the ID from this table to identify which language option is chosen:

   Arabic - mother tongue
      Arabic - Level B1
      English - mother tongue
      English - Level B1
3. So then when the form is submitted and the values sent back to the server, you can record which option IDs the user chose by using that single value, and later if you want to output the descriptions against somewhere else, you can JOIN the LanguageOptions table to the User options table using SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that
I see 2 possible solutions

1 JSON

```
      <select class="multi-select" name=""
    id=""
    multiple
    v-model="sprachen">
    <option  value='{language:"Arabic", level: "Muttersprache", image: "https://bilder.pcwelt.de/4204696_620x310_r.jpg"}' >Arabisch</option>
   ...
  </select>
```

2 comma separated value

```
  <select class="multi-select" name=""
    id=""
    multiple
    v-model="sprachen">
    <option  value='Arabic,Muttersprache,https://bilder.pcwelt.de/4204696_620x310_r.jpg' >Arabisch</option>
   ...
  </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I get the values in SQL and send them in Vuejs?